# Converting epoch time to "real" date/time

Tags: c++, algorithm, datetime, epoch

What I want to do is convert an epoch time (seconds since midnight 1/1/1970) to "real" time (m/d/y h:m:s)

So far, I have the following algorithm, which to me feels a bit ugly:

```
void DateTime::splitTicks(time_t time) {
    seconds = time % 60;
    time /= 60;
    minutes = time % 60;
    time /= 60;
    hours = time % 24;
    time /= 24;

    year = DateTime::reduceDaysToYear(time);
    month = DateTime::reduceDaysToMonths(time,year);
    day = int(time);
}

int DateTime::reduceDaysToYear(time_t &days) {
    int year;
    for (year=1970;days>daysInYear(year);year++) {
        days -= daysInYear(year);
    }
    return year;
}

int DateTime::reduceDaysToMonths(time_t &days,int year) {
    int month;
    for (month=0;days>daysInMonth(month,year);month++)
        days -= daysInMonth(month,year);
    return month;
}
```

you can assume that the members `seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`, `month`, `day`, and `year` all exist.

Using the `for` loops to modify the original time feels a little off, and I was wondering if there is a "better" solution to this.

Comment: What's wrong with just calling to this functionality as exposed by `time.h`, e.g. by [gmtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/gmtime/) if GMT rather than some specific timezone is what you're after?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, I did not even know it existed. Thanks! But, I am still interested to know how my implementation could be better.

Comment: @Austin, "thanks" and no upvote is not compliant with normal SO etiquette!-)

Comment: (Let me haste to indicate that this isn't self-serving, as I'm maxed out for the day anyway: it's about smooth and normal application of SO's basic etiquette -- you upvote answers you find helpful!!!).

Comment: @Alex, I just haven't gotten there yet. Don't worry :D

Comment: OK, so I know you're looking for a procedural solution... but if you haven't seen it already, check out http://www.epochconverter.com. It is a very useful way to check your work :)

Comment: For a non-iterative algorithm on how to do this computation see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32158604/576911

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Be careful about leap years in your daysInMonth function.

If you want very high performance, you can precompute the  pair to get to month+year in one step, and then calculate the day/hour/min/sec.

A good solution is the one in the [gmtime source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc#4kyKlxPG9x4/current/l4minix-03-03-10/src/lib/l4mxc/ansi/gmtime.c&q=gmtime):

```
/*
 * gmtime - convert the calendar time into broken down time
 */
/* $Header: gmtime.c,v 1.4 91/04/22 13:20:27 ceriel Exp $ */

#include        <time.h>
#include        <limits.h>
#include        "loc_time.h"

struct tm *
gmtime(register const time_t *timer)
{
        static struct tm br_time;
        register struct tm *timep = &br_time;
        time_t time = *timer;
        register unsigned long dayclock, dayno;
        int year = EPOCH_YR;

        dayclock = (unsigned long)time % SECS_DAY;
        dayno = (unsigned long)time / SECS_DAY;

        timep->tm_sec = dayclock % 60;
        timep->tm_min = (dayclock % 3600) / 60;
        timep->tm_hour = dayclock / 3600;
        timep->tm_wday = (dayno + 4) % 7;       /* day 0 was a thursday */
        while (dayno >= YEARSIZE(year)) {
                dayno -= YEARSIZE(year);
                year++;
        }
        timep->tm_year = year - YEAR0;
        timep->tm_yday = dayno;
        timep->tm_mon = 0;
        while (dayno >= _ytab[LEAPYEAR(year)][timep->tm_mon]) {
                dayno -= _ytab[LEAPYEAR(year)][timep->tm_mon];
                timep->tm_mon++;
        }
        timep->tm_mday = dayno + 1;
        timep->tm_isdst = 0;

        return timep;
}
```

Comment: Link to the gmtime source code is broken.

Answer (score 18):

The standard library provides functions for doing this. `gmtime()` or `localtime()` will convert a `time_t` (seconds since the epoch, i.e.- Jan 1 1970 00:00:00) into a `struct tm`. `strftime()` can then be used to convert a `struct tm` into a string (`char*`) based on the format you specify.

see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/

Date/time calculations can get tricky. You are much better off using an existing solution rather than trying to roll your own, unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: This started off as homework a while back, but now I am interested in making it better. Normally, I would go for the library solution, but 1) I didn't know the time functions were built in and 2) I want to perfect my implementation.

Comment: One of the good reasons is to avoid the expensive `__tz_convert` call

Answer (score 5):

An easy way (though different than the format you wanted):

```
std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result));
```

Output:
Wed Sep 21 10:27:52 2011

Notice that the returned result will be automatically concatenated with "\n".. you can remove it using:

```
std::string::size_type i = res.find("\n");
if (i != std::string::npos)
    res.erase(i, res.length());
```

Taken from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time

Comment: time.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
time.cpp:6:36: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);

Answer (score 4):

```
time_t t = unixTime;
cout << ctime(&t) << endl;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This code might help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   // current date/time based on current system
   time_t now = time(0);
   
   // convert now to string form
   char* dt = ctime(&now);

   cout << "The local date and time is: " << dt << endl;

   // convert now to tm struct for UTC
   tm *gmtm = gmtime(&now);
   dt = asctime(gmtm);
   cout << "The UTC date and time is:"<< dt << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a epoch string to UTC

```cpp
string epoch_to_utc(string epoch) {
  long temp = stol(epoch);
  const time_t old = (time_t)temp;
  struct tm *oldt = gmtime(&old);
  return asctime(oldt);
}
```

and then it can be called as

```cpp
  string temp = "245446047";
  cout << epoch_to_utc(temp);
```

outputs:

```
Tue Oct 11 19:27:27 1977
```

Comment: Nice,
how to print it in `1977-10-11 19:27:27` format?

Answer (score 0):

If your original time type is time_t, you have to use functions from time.h i.e. gmtime etc. to get portable code. The C/C++ standards do not specify internal format (or even exact type) for the time_t, so you cannot directly convert or manipulate time_t values.

All that is known is that time_t is "arithmetic type", but results of arithmetic operations are not specified - you cannot even add/subtract reliably. In practice, many systems use integer type for time_t with internal format of seconds since epoch, but this is not enforced by standards.

In short, use gmtime (and time.h functionality in general).