# Convert Epoch Time string to Time

Tags: c, linux, unix, time, epoch

I've been looking for a way to convert a string (in Epoch time) into a date.

Basically, I need to take this: `1360440555` (in string form) and make it into this: `Feb  9 12:09 2013`.

I've been looking at strptime and strftime, but neither seems to be working for me. Any suggestions?

Edit: Thanks, guys. I converted it to an int with `atoi()`, cast it as `time_t`, then ran `ctime()` on it. Worked perfectly!

Comment: "neither seems to be working for me". How are you calling them and what happens?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897445/how-to-convert-epoch-time-to-time-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If only you had that value in an integer instead of a string, you could just call `ctime`.  If only there were some way to convert a string to an integer....

```
time_t c;
c = strtoul( "1360440555", NULL, 0 );
ctime( &c );
```

Comment: +1 for sarcasm.  But it gives no help,  may be had you asked can you spell strtoul() would have worked better.  ctime takes time_t BTW.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to convert a string to an integer, since there's no `strtoll()` function in the standard library...

Comment: note: in Standard C it's not guaranteed that `time_t` is the seconds since epoch. It is in glibc but IDK about other places.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`%s` (GNU extension)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime), to  convert POSIX timestamp given as a string to the broken-down time `tm`:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    struct tm tm;
    char buf[255];

    memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    strptime("1360440555", "%s", &tm);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%b %d %H:%M %Y", &tm);
    puts(buf); /* -> Feb 09 20:09 2013 */
    return 0;
}
```

Note: the local timezone is UTC (with other timezone the result is different).