# How to convert unsigned int 64 into time in C++?

Tags: c++, datetime, time, c++-cli

I am converting CLI C++ code to standard C++, and i have a piece of code that gets a UINT64 number (from a remote server - so i can't change to format/precision of the time i get) and converts it into DateTime object and later outputs the following value: myDatetime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fffffff tt").
I haven't found a way to convert unsigned int 64 into time in C++. 
The following code does nothing for numbers so big (that's the 64bit number i get from the server).

```
time_t rawtime=131274907755873979
localtime_s(&timeinfo, &rawtime);
```

I need some help :)

My question wan't answered in the thread [Convert Epoch Time string to Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792658/convert-epoch-time-string-to-time) since it doesn't work for numbers as large as i need. For example the number 131274907755873979 which is what i get from the server. The function ctime for that value simply returns NULL. 
I need a way to convert between the time i get as a unsigned int64 into standard C++ time object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Epoch Time string to Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792658/convert-epoch-time-string-to-time)

Comment: You don't suppose that the conversion of that number into a DateTime object might be the slightest bit pertinent to the question, do you?

Comment: Regarding "standard C++ time object". C++11 or more recent an acceptable standard?

Comment: Best would be C++11 since i am not sure what compiler version i am gonna have on our production servers. But C++14 will also be acceptable i hope

Comment: Groovy. [Howard Hinnant's time libraries may be helpful to you.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) Some Epoch conversion (see @MikeNakis 's answer below) may be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string LongToString(int64_t longDate) {        
    char buff[128];

    std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::milli> dur(longDate);
    auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point(
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::system_clock::duration>(dur));
    std::time_t in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    strftime(buff, 128, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&in_time_t));
    std::string resDate(buff);
    
    return resDate;

}
```

This is a case with bsoncxx::types::b_date get_date().to_int64() MongoDB.

The DateTime saved with int64_t.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You have not told us how the existing code converts that number into a `DateTime`.  Let us suppose that it does so by invoking this constructor: `DateTime( long long ticks )`.

According to [**the documentation of that constructor of DateTime**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1),

> **long long ticks** A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.

On the other hand, according to [**the documentation of localtime_s**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) and [**the documentation of time_t**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t), `localtime_s()` requires

> the number of seconds (not counting leap seconds) since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC.

So, you first need to convert 100-nanosecond intervals to seconds, and then convert from January 1, 0001 to January 1, 1970.

Comment: The way it currently works is by using the  DateTime::FromFileTime function to convert the unsigned int64 into a DateTime object.

Comment: Same thing, according to [**the documentation of FromFileTime**] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: what do yuo mean by: "So, you first need to convert 100-nanosecond intervals to seconds, and then convert from January 1, 0001 to January 1, 1970" - how do i doo this conversion?

Comment: Uh, that's not a programming question. How about taking it to https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Howard Hinnant's datetime library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) this computation can be done quite easily.  It works with VS 2013 and later.

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string
FILETIME_to_string(std::uint64_t i)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    using FileTime = duration<int64_t, ratio<1, 10000000>>;
    auto const offset = sys_days{jan/1/1970} - sys_days{jan/1/1601};
    auto tp = sys_days{jan/1/1970} + (FileTime{static_cast<int64_t>(i)} - offset);
    return format("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", make_zoned("Etc/GMT-2", tp));
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << FILETIME_to_string(131274907755873979) << '\n';
}
```

This skips `DateTime` and goes straight to the `string`.  I wasn't sure what you are wanting with `tt` in the format.  But whatever it is, it can be handled.

This library builds on the C++11 `<chrono>` library.  So the first thing to do is to create a duration to represent the windows tick size (100 ns).  Then just compute the offset between the two epochs and subtract it from the input, and form a `std::chrono::time_point`.  Now you can format that `time_point` however you want.

The program above outputs:

```
29/12/2016 03:12:55.5873979 PM
```

If you use VS 2017 you'll be able to make `offset` `constexpr`, making the conversion more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But my job doesn't allow the use of third party libraries. Is it possible to do this with the build in chrono library?

Comment: @primeQuestion:  Yes, my entire library is portably built on top of `<chrono>`.  You'll need to compute the number of `0.1 microseconds` between the two epoch dates, subtract that off your input, then convert that into a `{year, month, day, hour, minute, second, fractional second}` data structure, and then format it.  Here is a paper with calendrical formulas to help you:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html

Comment: Thanks. Why did you use jan/1/1601 as the epoh date for Windows? Isn't it  January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000?

Comment: Also - the "tt"  is supposed to output PM or AM. the proper output for 131274907755873979 in the original code is 9/12/2016 03:12:55.5873979 PM. So it's slightly different form yours. Maybe due to the "tt"?

Comment: I used jan/1/1601 because I guessed that you are using something based off of the Windows Filetime epoch (which is 1601-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).  When I used that epoch, your sample input gave a reasonable output, and so I assumed my guess was correct.

Comment: I've reformatted my answer to the style you want (12 hour clock).  It still doesn't match your desired output.  It is off by 20 days and 2 hours.  My best guess is that you've got a 20 day mistake in your computation, and that you would like a 2h timezone offset.  My library can handle timezone offsets using the IANA timezone names, or the machine's current local timezone.

Comment: @ Howard Hinnant - thanks a lot. I made a mistake and copied the wrong timestamp - the value 131274907755873979 gives a timestamp of 29/12/2016 03:12:55.5873979 PM. So it's really close. But for some reason it's still off by 2 hours. I have just checked it in VS using DateTime.FromFileTime. So that's the corresponding timestamp of this number. Is it possible to adjust your code so it outputs the same value?

Comment: Done.  I needed to add a "timezone" which IANA calls "Etc/GMT-2", which for dumb reasons means UTC _plus_ 2h, not UTC _minus_ 2h.

Comment: @ Howard Hinnant Thanks a lot. Can you please help me a bit so i can write this using only chrono? I am not sure what you mean in the post when you said "So the first thing to do is to create a duration to represent the windows tick size (100 ns). Then just compute the offset between the two epochs and subtract it from the input, and from a std::chrono::time_point" - can you explain/give example to what you mean? Also, how do i format the time_point-  how do i convert it into text?

Comment: What I mean is that it is doable.  I didn't say it was easy.  I've been perfecting this library for a couple of years now.  I don't recommend trying to write it yourself.  But if you want to, the underlying formulas are freely available here:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html .  You are welcome to inspect the source code (it is open source).  But I ask that you respect the copyright, which means including the copyright in your code if you use the source, or a derivation of it.  It is the MIT license which is intended to be as permissive as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain that line - sys_days{jan/1/1970} + (FileTime{static_cast<int64_t>(i)} - offset);? I am not sure why you add sys_days{jan/1/1970}? Wasn't the point to subtract it via offset?

Comment: does this project work on Linux? The code i need has to run on a Linux platform.

Comment: Yes, with gcc-5 or later and `-std=c++11` or later.

Comment: Thanks i will try that soon. In the meantime it works on Windows but only witohut the make_zoned function addition. When adding that it crushes. It said in an error message that the tzdata was missing. So i created it and downloaded timezone data from IANA there. But now it throws the error - "Error opening time zone mapping file \"C:\\Users\\ed\\Downloads\\tzdata\\windowsZones.xml\"." Where do i get this file from?

Comment: Here are the installation instructions for using the timezone part of this library: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation  This includes links for the IANA tzdatabase, and options for installing these files automatically (requires curl and 7-zip on Windows).