# Math to convert seconds since 1970 into date and vice versa

Tags: c++, date, math

I have seconds since Jan 1 1970 00:00 as an int64 in nanoseconds and I'm trying to convert it into month/day/year/day of week.

It's easy to do this iteratively, I have that working but I want to do it formulaically. I'm looking for the actual math.

Comment: are you aware of `<ctime>` functions?

Comment: There must be a thousand implementations of this  .... lookup Unix time, time_t or ctime on google.

Comment: as a floating point number? Really?

Comment: @jkerian Yes, so 0.01 represents Jan 1, 1970 00:00:01 (I need sub-second precision, and even sub-milliseconds which is why it's a double)

Comment: If you want precision, you want a (large) integral type (representing microseconds or what-have-you). You **Don't** want to use floating point if precision is what you're after. Too many strange corner-cases.

Comment: @jkerian Yeah, that's probably a good idea. You would max out a 64bit integer representing microseconds in ~585k years though.

Comment: Time is a complicated subject.  This is going to depend heavily on your calendar and timezone.  There's a great book called [Calendrical Calculations](http://www.amazon.com/Calendrical-Calculations-Millennium-Edward-Reingold/dp/0521777526/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1320231356&sr=8-2) that covers the actual mathematics of time conversions in great detail.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

New answer for old question:

Rationale for this new answer: The existing answers either do not show the algorithms for the conversion from nanoseconds to year/month/day (e.g. they use libraries with the source hidden), or they use iteration in the algorithms they do show.

This answer has no iteration whatsoever.

[The algorithms are here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html), and explained in excruciating detail.  They are also unit tested for correctness over a span of +/- a million years (way more than you need).

The algorithms don't count leap seconds.  If you need that, it can be done, but requires a table lookup, and that table grows with time.

The date algorithms deal only with units of days, and not nanoseconds.  To convert days to nanoseconds, multiply by `86400*1000000000` (taking care to ensure you're using 64 bit arithmetic).  To convert nanoseconds to days, divide by the same amount.  Or better yet, use the C++11 `<chrono>` library.

There are three date algorithms from this paper that are needed to answer this question.

`1.`  `days_from_civil`:

```
// Returns number of days since civil 1970-01-01.  Negative values indicate
//    days prior to 1970-01-01.
// Preconditions:  y-m-d represents a date in the civil (Gregorian) calendar
//                 m is in [1, 12]
//                 d is in [1, last_day_of_month(y, m)]
//                 y is "approximately" in
//                   [numeric_limits<Int>::min()/366, numeric_limits<Int>::max()/366]
//                 Exact range of validity is:
//                 [civil_from_days(numeric_limits<Int>::min()),
//                  civil_from_days(numeric_limits<Int>::max()-719468)]
template <class Int>
constexpr
Int
days_from_civil(Int y, unsigned m, unsigned d) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits >= 18,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit unsigned integer");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<Int>::digits >= 20,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit signed integer");
    y -= m <= 2;
    const Int era = (y >= 0 ? y : y-399) / 400;
    const unsigned yoe = static_cast<unsigned>(y - era * 400);      // [0, 399]
    const unsigned doy = (153*(m + (m > 2 ? -3 : 9)) + 2)/5 + d-1;  // [0, 365]
    const unsigned doe = yoe * 365 + yoe/4 - yoe/100 + doy;         // [0, 146096]
    return era * 146097 + static_cast<Int>(doe) - 719468;
}
```

`2.`  `civil_from_days`:

```
// Returns year/month/day triple in civil calendar
// Preconditions:  z is number of days since 1970-01-01 and is in the range:
//                   [numeric_limits<Int>::min(), numeric_limits<Int>::max()-719468].
template <class Int>
constexpr
std::tuple<Int, unsigned, unsigned>
civil_from_days(Int z) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits >= 18,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit unsigned integer");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<Int>::digits >= 20,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit signed integer");
    z += 719468;
    const Int era = (z >= 0 ? z : z - 146096) / 146097;
    const unsigned doe = static_cast<unsigned>(z - era * 146097);          // [0, 146096]
    const unsigned yoe = (doe - doe/1460 + doe/36524 - doe/146096) / 365;  // [0, 399]
    const Int y = static_cast<Int>(yoe) + era * 400;
    const unsigned doy = doe - (365*yoe + yoe/4 - yoe/100);                // [0, 365]
    const unsigned mp = (5*doy + 2)/153;                                   // [0, 11]
    const unsigned d = doy - (153*mp+2)/5 + 1;                             // [1, 31]
    const unsigned m = mp + (mp < 10 ? 3 : -9);                            // [1, 12]
    return std::tuple<Int, unsigned, unsigned>(y + (m <= 2), m, d);
}
```

`3.` `weekday_from_days`:

```
// Returns day of week in civil calendar [0, 6] -> [Sun, Sat]
// Preconditions:  z is number of days since 1970-01-01 and is in the range:
//                   [numeric_limits<Int>::min(), numeric_limits<Int>::max()-4].
template <class Int>
constexpr
unsigned
weekday_from_days(Int z) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<unsigned>(z >= -4 ? (z+4) % 7 : (z+5) % 7 + 6);
}
```

These algorithms are written for C++14.  If you have C++11, remove the `constexpr`.  If you have C++98/03, remove the `constexpr`, the `noexcept`, and the `static_assert`s.

Note the lack of iteration in any of these three algorithms.

They can be used like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    int64_t z = days_from_civil(2015LL, 8, 22);
    int64_t ns = z*86400*1000000000;
    std::cout << ns << '\n';
    const char* weekdays[] = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
    unsigned wd = weekday_from_days(z);
    int64_t y;
    unsigned m, d;
    std::tie(y, m, d) = civil_from_days(ns/86400/1000000000);
    std::cout << y << '-' << m << '-' << d << ' ' << weekdays[wd] << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
1440201600000000000
2015-8-22 Sat
```

The algorithms are in the public domain.  Use them however you want.  The [date algorithms paper](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) has several more useful date algorithms if needed (e.g. `weekday_difference` is both remarkably simple and remarkably useful).

These algorithms are wrapped up in an [open source, cross platform, type-safe date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) if needed.

If timezone or leap second support is needed, there exists a [timezone library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) built on top of the [date library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).

**Update:  Different local zones in same app**

See how to [convert among different time zones](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#convert).

**Update:** Are there any pitfalls to ignoring leap seconds when doing date calculations in this manner?

This is a good question from the comments below.

*Answer:* There are some pitfalls.  And there are some benefits.  It is good to know what they both are.

Almost every source of time from an OS is based on [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is a count of time since 1970-01-01 *excluding* leap seconds.  This includes functions like the C `time(nullptr)` and the C++ `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`, as well as the POSIX `gettimeofday` and `clock_gettime`.  This is not a fact specified by the standard (except it is specified by POSIX), but it is the de facto standard.

So if your source of seconds (nanoseconds, whatever) neglects leap seconds, it is exactly correct to ignore leap seconds when converting to field types such as `{year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, nanoseconds}`.  In fact to take leap seconds into account in such a context would actually *introduce* errors.

So it is good to know your source of time, and especially to know if it also neglects leap seconds as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) does.

If your source of time *does not* neglect leap seconds, you can *still* get the correct answer down to the second.  You just need to know the set of leap seconds that have been inserted.  [Here is the current list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

For example if you get a count of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC which *includes* leap seconds and you know that this represents "now" (which is currently 2016-09-26), the current number of leap seconds inserted between now and 1970-01-01 is 26.  So you could subtract 26 from your count, and *then* follow these algorithms, getting the exact result.

[This library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) can automate leap-second-aware computations for you.  For example to get the number of seconds between 2016-09-26 00:00:00 UTC and 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC *including* leap seconds, you could do this:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    auto now  = clock_cast<utc_clock>(sys_days{2016_y/September/26});
    auto then = clock_cast<utc_clock>(sys_days{1970_y/January/1});
    std::cout << now - then << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
1474848026s
```

Neglecting leap seconds ([Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) looks like:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto now  = sys_days{2016_y/September/26} + 0s;
    auto then = sys_days{1970_y/January/1};
    std::cout << now - then << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
1474848000s
```

For a difference of `26s`.

This upcoming New Years (2017-01-01) we will insert the 27<sup>*th*</sup> leap second.

Between 1958-01-01 and 1970-01-01 10 "leap seconds" were inserted, but in units smaller than a second, and not just at the end of Dec or Jun.  Documentation on exactly how much time was inserted and exactly when is sketchy, and I have not been able to track down a reliable source.

Atomic time keeping services began experimentally in 1955, and the first  atomic-based international time standard TAI has an epoch of 1958-01-01 00:00:00 GMT (what is now UTC).  Prior to that the best we had was quartz-based clocks which were not accurate enough to worry about leap seconds.

Comment: Your time zone library is a remarkable work. I was looking for something equivalent for C. I planed to use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_TAI,...)` which removes the leap second ambiguity and jump back of `CLOCK_REALTIME`. But then I need to access the time zone database wich is nicely self documented.  I'm working on this time representation https://github.com/chmike/timez. Your code will be a huge help. Does chrono also provide TAI time reference ? Do you use TAI time reference ? Note that on web forums, people may want to use different local time in the same app.

Comment: @chmike:  I've updated my answer to address both of your points.  Thanks!

Comment: I would need a little help to understand your code for the TAI update because I'm not very familiar with the C++ chrono library. In fact I'm already confused by the 26s difference between the unix time and utc time. Reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time (n'th time), the table showing the crossing of a leap second is confusing. As I understand it, TAI is based on a count of seconds without leap second addition. UTC has a leap second added while the Unix time has a leap second subtracted relative to TAI ?! How does the respective  second  counts evolve when a leap second is inserted ?

Comment: @chmike:  You're right.  I've removed my too-quickly-cobbled-together `tai_clock`.  No matter how small the software project, if you rush it, you'll mess it up... :-)

Comment: After thinking a night on it, I now think that the second count elapsed since the Unix time epoch is the same for UTC ant TAI. So the only mistake I assume there was in your code is the 10s leap second subtraction. Beside this I'm curious how std::chrono handles leap seconds because there is an ambiguity at that moment with the Unix/system time when it converts system time into UTC time.

Comment: Right, but to really fill a `tai_clock` out nicely it needs functionality to correctly convert to `y/md h:ms:s` field types with the expected difference from UTC.

Comment: `std::chrono` does not address leap seconds.  Officially, the epochs of all the std::chrono::clocks is left unspecified.  Unofficially, every implementation of `std::chrono::system_clock` implements Unix Time:  i.e. a count of non-leap-seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC.  My tz.h IANA parser that I've written on top of `std::chrono` simply adds/subtracts the proper number of leap seconds from a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.  Source code: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/tz.h#L598-L658

Comment: @chmike:  Fwiw, I finally got around to writing, documenting, testing `tai_clock`: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#tai_clock The documentation includes an example (after `gps_clock`) which also answers your old question about how this library handles the ambiguous mapping between UTC and Unix Time.

Comment: Are there any pitfalls to ignoring leap seconds when doing date calculations in this manner?

Comment: @mindeavor:  I updated my answer to address your good question.

Answer (score 13):

The Single Unix Specification gives a formula for [Seconds since the Epoch](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_14):

> A value that approximates the number of seconds that have elapsed
>   since the Epoch. A Coordinated Universal Time name (specified in terms
>   of seconds (tm_sec), minutes (tm_min), hours (tm_hour), days since
>   January 1 of the year (tm_yday), and calendar year minus 1900
>   (tm_year)) is related to a time represented as seconds since the
>   Epoch, according to the expression below.
>
> If the year is <1970 or the value is negative, the relationship is
>   undefined. If the year is >=1970 and the value is non-negative, the
>   value is related to a Coordinated Universal Time name according to the
>   C-language expression, where tm_sec, tm_min, tm_hour, tm_yday, and
>   tm_year are all integer types:
>
> ```
> tm_sec + tm_min*60 + tm_hour*3600 + tm_yday*86400 +
>     (tm_year-70)*31536000 + ((tm_year-69)/4)*86400 -
>     ((tm_year-1)/100)*86400 + ((tm_year+299)/400)*86400
> ```
>
> The relationship between the actual time of day and the current value
>   for seconds since the Epoch is unspecified.
>
> How any changes to the value of seconds since the Epoch are made to
>   align to a desired relationship with the current actual time is
>   implementation-defined. As represented in seconds since the Epoch,
>   each and every day shall be accounted for by exactly 86400 seconds.
>
> Note:
>       The last three terms of the expression add in a day for each year that follows a leap year starting with the first leap year since the
>   Epoch. The first term adds a day every 4 years starting in 1973, the
>   second subtracts a day back out every 100 years starting in 2001, and
>   the third adds a day back in every 400 years starting in 2001. The
>   divisions in the formula are integer divisions; that is, the remainder
>   is discarded leaving only the integer quotient.

You'll need to convert month and day of month to tm_yday to use this formula and that too should be done taking into account leap years. The rest in the formula is trivial.

Try to figure out from this how to get back date and time from seconds.

**EDIT**:

I've implemented a convertor in integer arithmetic in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197532/968261).

[See a test run at ideone](http://ideone.com/7BADb).

Answer (score 2):

```
bool FloatToTime(float seconds_since_epoch, bool local_time, struct tm *timest)
{
   struct tm *ret;
   time_t t=(time_t) seconds_since_epoch;
   if (local_time) ret=localtime(&t);
      else ret=gmtime(&t);
   if(ret==NULL) return false;
   memcpy(timest, ret, sizeof(struct tm));
   return true;
}
```

Pass it the seconds as the first parameter. The second parameter should be true for local time, false for GMT. The third parameter is a pointer to a structure to hold the response.

The return structures are (from the man page):

> tm_sec:    The number of seconds after the minute, normally in the range 0 to
>                  59, but can be up to 60 to allow for leap seconds.
>
> tm_min:    The number of minutes after the hour, in the range 0 to 59.
>
> tm_hour:   The number of hours past midnight, in the range 0 to 23.
>
> tm_mday:   The day of the month, in the range 1 to 31.
>
> tm_mon:    The number of months since January, in the range 0 to 11.
>
> tm_year:   The number of years since 1900.
>
> tm_wday:   The number of days since Sunday, in the range 0 to 6.
>
> tm_yday:   The number of days since January 1, in the range 0 to 365.
>
> tm_isdst:  A flag that indicates whether daylight saving time is in effect
>                  at the time described.  The value is positive if daylight saving
>                  time is in effect, zero if it is not, and negative if the
>                  information is not available.

Comment: I think in your memcpy you mean memcpy(timest, ret, sizeof(struct tm)) ??

Answer (score 2):

Depends on which time you want [gmtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/gmtime/) or [localtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/) then just read the [struct_tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/)

Answer (score 2):

This code works...

Usage:
uint32_t getSecsSinceEpoch(1970, month, day, years_since_epoch, hour, minute, second);

Example:
timestamp = getSecsSinceEpoch(1970, 6, 12, (2014 - 1970), 15, 29, 0)

Returns: 1402586940

You can verify at www.epochconverter.com.

Took about 20 mins to write it and most of that was spent arguing with a friend as to whether I should include leap-seconds, nano-seconds, etc.  Blech.

Have fun...

Dr. Bryan Wilcutt

```
#define DAYSPERWEEK (7)
#define DAYSPERNORMYEAR (365U)
#define DAYSPERLEAPYEAR (366U)

#define SECSPERDAY (86400UL) /* == ( 24 * 60 * 60) */
#define SECSPERHOUR (3600UL) /* == ( 60 * 60) */
#define SECSPERMIN (60UL) /* == ( 60) */

#define LEAPYEAR(year)          (!((year) % 4) && (((year) % 100) || !((year) % 400)))

const int _ytab[2][12] = {
{31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
{31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
};

/****************************************************
* Class:Function    : getSecsSomceEpoch
* Input     : uint16_t epoch date (ie, 1970)
* Input     : uint8 ptr to returned month
* Input     : uint8 ptr to returned day
* Input     : uint8 ptr to returned years since Epoch
* Input     : uint8 ptr to returned hour
* Input     : uint8 ptr to returned minute
* Input     : uint8 ptr to returned seconds
* Output        : uint32_t Seconds between Epoch year and timestamp
* Behavior      :
*
* Converts MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS to actual seconds since epoch.
* Epoch year is assumed at Jan 1, 00:00:01am.
****************************************************/
uint32_t getSecsSinceEpoch(uint16_t epoch, uint8_t month, uint8_t day, uint8_t years, uint8_t hour, uint8_t minute, uint8_t second)
{
unsigned long secs = 0;
int countleap = 0;
int i;
int dayspermonth;

secs = years * (SECSPERDAY * 365);
for (i = 0; i < (years - 1); i++)
{   
    if (LEAPYEAR((epoch + i)))
      countleap++;
}
secs += (countleap * SECSPERDAY);

secs += second;
secs += (hour * SECSPERHOUR);
secs += (minute * SECSPERMIN);
secs += ((day - 1) * SECSPERDAY);

if (month > 1)
{
    dayspermonth = 0;

    if (LEAPYEAR((epoch + years))) // Only counts when we're on leap day or past it
    {
        if (month > 2)
        {
            dayspermonth = 1;
        } else if (month == 2 && day >= 29) {
            dayspermonth = 1;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < month - 1; i++)
    {   
        secs += (_ytab[dayspermonth][i] * SECSPERDAY);
    }
}

return secs;
}
```

Comment: OP explicitly asked for a non-iterative approach.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not store your seconds as a float.  If you need micro/nanoseconds, store them separately.  You're going to need integers to do these calculations.

It depends on your time zone (DST rules, leap years, leap seconds), but I would say first get the number of days by integer dividing by 86400.  Then find out what's left over, by modulo dividing by 86400.  Now you can figure out how many years have passed by first integer dividing the number of days by 365, and then subtracting the number of leap days from the remaining days (calculated by modulo dividing the number of days by 365).  You'll also want to subtract the number of leap seconds from the number of remaining seconds (already calculated).  If that subtraction drives those numbers below zero, then subtract from the next biggest denomination.  Then you can calculate the day of month using explicit logic for your calendar.  Make sure to add an hour (or whatever the DST offset is) if you land in DST.

Personally, I would just use [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/date_time.html), since it does all this and more (probably with fewer mistakes than you or I would make in the first few iterations), but I figured I'd take a shot at your question...

Comment: I do not agree with the knee-jerk "do not use floating-point" remark. It is possible to use `double` as a 52-bit integer type if you do not have 64-bit integers on some platform. It is furthermore possible to use them for fixed-point computations. Yes, you lose precision if you exceed the allowable range and things may become erratic, but with integers, the behavior is undefined if you exceed the allowable range. Just be careful not to exceed it in either case.

Comment: can you do modulo division with floats?  i mean, without first converting them?  if so, then I guess my calculations will work.  I haven't tried it though, because I just assumed they wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, you can compute the modulo using function `fmod()`. To expand on my previous comment, IEEE 754 mandates that for a number of operations that if the result can be represented exactly as floating-point number, then the result returned by this floating-point operation is that number. In the case of `fmod` of two doubles that represent integers, the result, an integer, can be represented exactly. Actually, I believe the result of `fmod()` is always exact, for arbitrary finite arguments.

Comment: cool, I wasn't aware of that.  So you would still have to floor() the floating point number to an integer before using fmod() right?  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

BEFORE

```
    for (i = 0; i < (years - 1); i++)
    {   
        if (LEAPYEAR((epoch + i)))
        countleap++;
    }
```

LATER:

```
    for (i = 0; i < years; i++)
 {   
   if (LEAPYEAR((epoch + i)))
    countleap++;
 }
```

After the correction the code worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to implement conversion to Unix time at a low-end 8-bit MCU without HW multiplier. Below is the C# code that requires only a general 8-bit multiplication and a division by constant values 4 and 100. Both on 32-bit (long) operand. The C# code can be easily ported to the final framework. It gives the same result as *DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds()* from .NET.

```
static long UnixTime ( int sec, int min, int hour, int day, int month, int year )
{
  // Cumulative days for each previous month of the year
  int[] mdays = { 0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334 };
  // Year is to be relative to the epoch start
  year -= 1970;
  // Compensation of the non-leap years
  int minusYear = 0;
  // Detect potential lead day (February 29th) in this year?
  if ( month >= 3 )
  {
    // Then add this year into "sum of leap days" computation
    year++;
    // Compute one year less in the non-leap years sum
    minusYear = 1;
  }

  return 
    // + Seconds from computed minutes
    60 * (
      // + Minutes from computed hours
      60 * (
        // + Hours from computed days
        24 * (
          // + Day (zero index)
          day - 1
          // + days in previous months (leap day not included)
          + mdays[month - 1]
          // + days for each year divisible by 4 (starting from 1973)
          + ( ( year + 1 ) / 4 )
          // - days for each year divisible by 100 (starting from 2001)
          - ( ( year + 69 ) / 100 )
          // + days for each year divisible by 400 (starting from 2001)
          + ( ( year + 369 ) / 100 / 4 )
          // + days for each year (as all are non-leap years) from 1970 (minus this year if potential leap day taken into account)
          + ( 5 * 73 /*=365*/ ) * ( year - minusYear )
          // + Hours
        ) + hour
        // + Minutes
      ) + min 
      // + Seconds
    ) + sec;
}
```

Hope it helps.

**Edited:**

Below is the optimized code for 8-bit PIC MCU and CC5X compiler.

```
uns32 unixTime;

...
  // Test data returning 0xFfFfFfFf UnixTime
  uns8 year = 2106 - 1970;
  uns8 month = 2;
  uns8 day = 7;
  uns8 hour = 6;
  uns8 min = 28;
  uns8 sec = 15;

  // See original C# code below

  //### Compute days
  // ( 5 * 73 /*=365*/ ) * year
  unixTime = year;
  mulUnixTime( 5 );
  mulUnixTime( 73 );

  // if ( month >= 3 ) year++;
  if ( month > 3 )
    year++;

  // if ( year > 130 ) => minus 1 total days ( year-=4 makes a result of the next division by 4 less by 1)
  if ( year > 130 )
    year -= 4;
  // + ( ( year + 1 ) / 4 )
  addUnixTime( ( year + 1 ) / 4 );
  // + mdays[month - 1]
  addUnixTime( daysInMonths( month ) );
  // + day - 1
  addUnixTime( day - 1 );
  //### Compute hours
  // Hours from computed days
  mulUnixTime( 24 );
  // + Hours
  addUnixTime( hour );
  //### Compute minutes
  // Minutes from computed hours 
  mulUnixTime( 60 );
  // + Minutes
  addUnixTime( min );
  //### Compute seconds
  // Seconds from computed minutes
  mulUnixTime( 60 );
  // + Seconds
  addUnixTime( sec );
...

void mulUnixTime( uns8 mul )
{
  unixTime *= mul;
}

void addUnixTime( uns8 add )
{
  unixTime += add;
}

uns8 daysInMonths( uns8 month @ W )
{
  skip( month );
#pragma computedGoto 1
  return 0xFF;// Dummy value for month 0
  return   0; // January
  return  31; // February
  return  59; // ...
  return  90;
  return 120;
  return 151;
  return 181;
  return 212;
  return 243;
  return 273;
  return 304; // ...
  return 334; // December
#pragma computedGoto 0
}


/*
 static long UnixTime ( int sec, int min, int hour, int day, int month, int year )
  {
    // Cumulative days for each previous month of the year
    int[] mdays = { 0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334 };
    // Year is to be relative to the epoch start
    year -= 1970;
    // Compensation of the non-leap years
    int minusYear = 0;
    // Detect potential lead day (February 29th) in this year?
    if ( month >= 3 )
    {
      // Then add this year into "sum of leap days" computation
      year++;
      // Compute one year less in the non-leap years sum
      minusYear = 1;
    }

    return
      // + Seconds from computed minutes
      60 * (
        // + Minutes from computed hours
        60 * (
          // + Hours from computed days
          24L * (
            // + Day (zero index)
            day - 1
            // + days in previous months (leap day not included)
            + mdays[month - 1]
            // + days for each year divisible by 4 (starting from 1973)
            + ( ( year + 1 ) / 4 )
            // - days after year 2000
            - ( ( year > 130 ) ? 1 : 0 )
            // + days for each year (as all are non-leap years) from 1970 (minus this year if potential leap day taken into account)
            + ( 5 * 73 ) * ( year - minusYear )
          // + Hours
          ) + hour
        // + Minutes
        ) + min
      // + Seconds
      ) + sec;
  }
*/
```

Comment: It would be good to note that the range of validity for this function is [1968-03-01 00:00:00, 2038-01-19 03:14:07].

Comment: Your are right, I needed only the dates after 1 January 1970 so the result is positive long only. I am not even sure about validity before 1970, I did not test it.
Also because between 1970 and 2038 only year 2000 is to be considered as divisible by 100 and 400 the expression can be even more simplified in this case when result is 32-bit. Also divison by 4 is enough to compute on byte only.