# Seconds since Epoch to formatted time

Tags: c++, date, datetime, string-formatting

I find it hard to believe this isn't on the website, yet I can't seem to find it.

I would like a function that takes in a format and a number, and returns a string of the date, i.e.

```cpp
std::string date = DateFromSecondsSinceEpoch("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", 1000000000); //2001-09-09 01:46:40

//or
std::string date = DateFromSecondsSinceEpoch("yyyy-mm-dd", 1000000000); //2001-09-09
```

With a function signature such as:

```cpp
std::string DateFromSecondsSinceEpoch(const char* format, const long long int seconds);
```

Comment: Have a look at things like [`std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/from_time_t), [`std::put_time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time), [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format), etc

Comment: duplicate: [Math to convert seconds since 1970 into date and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158604/995714)

Comment: For anyone who sees this post in the future, I didn't exactly find what I wanted in those links, but this here works very well, and answers my question.
`std::string DateFromSecondsSinceEpoch(const long long int seconds){    struct tm ts; char buf[11];    localtime_s(&ts, &seconds);    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d", &ts);    return buf;}
`