# C or C++ code to get hour of day from epoch timestamp using time-zone

Tags: c++, c, epoch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to convert epoch time to “real” date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692184/best-way-to-convert-epoch-time-to-real-date-time)

I need to write a small function in C/C++ which will take epoch time stamp and time-zone as input and return "hour" part of that time-stamp. Please help.

Comment: What is your platform/environment?

Comment: yes i have looked, i have done the same in java and looking for equivalent in C?? i m struck at time-zone thing

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `struct tm` and the `localtime()` function?

Comment: With `tzset()` to move the time zone around.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about parsing some text into a time then extracting the hour, `getdate()` is likely what you're looking for.